# Numerically solving 1D 2nd order PDE Goursat problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

I am looking for help with solving the following Goursat problem (this is what the paper I am reading from calls it).  I have been attempting a numerical solution in matlab but I do not fully understand the (internal?) boundary conditions and how to include them in my solution.  For simplicity sake, I have been assuming $ q(x)=0  $, and for the project that I'm working on it doesn't matter whether or not $ q(x)=0  $. I'm looking for advice or at least the direction to some literature where I can educate my self on the matter.

$$ k_{xx} - k_{ss} + q(x)k = 0,\ \ 0<x<s<l\\k(0,s)=0,  \ \ \ \ k(x,x)=-\frac 12\int_0^xq(\xi)d\xi $$

Please and thank you, Chris

Comment: You set $q(x)=0$  thus $k(x,x)=0$ So, the solution is obvious $k(x,s)=0$

Comment: @jjacqelin Thanks for confirming my suspicion, I came to that realization yesterday while working on the problem. Would still be interested in knowing how to approach a numerical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $q(\zeta)$ is a given function. Thus, the boundary condition $k(x,x)$ can be computed on each point of the boundary line.

So, all is known for the numetical compution on the discretized triangular domain.

[image]

Comment: Using a triangular domain.. That makes sense looking at your picture. For some reason I had it in my head that the domain had to be full length in the x coordinate for all s.  Much appreciated!!

Comment: I limited to a triangular domain according to the condition $0<x<s<l$ , as specified in the wording of the question. But the conditions on the supposed boundary $s=l$ are not clear.

Comment: The $ s=l $ boundary conditions are not specified in the paper that this problem comes from. The $ k(x,s) $ solution is used as the integral kernel in a solution to a 2nd order hyperbolic wave eq with 0 ICs and non constant BCs in the form of $ w_{tt} - w_{xx} + q(x)w = 0 $.  I'm reworking my code now but so far so good.